# Silverlight - Displaying Hierarchy of tabular data

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datagrid

I have some data that I am displaying in a DataGrid. This data has multiple properties, which represent the columns of the DataGrid. One of these properties is a collection of another type of entity.

When a user selects an item in the DataGrid, I want to show the collection of entities in a tabular structure. In a sense, I'm looking to create a DataGrid inside of the RowDetailsTemplate of a DataGrid. I am not set on using a DataGrid, I'm just using this because it is the only kind of control I am aware of that can display tabular information.

My problem is, I do not know how to create the XAML that addresses this type of binding structure. Can anyone show me some code or point me to a code example?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need the "Grid" to be editable?

Comment: No. The "Grid" does not need to be editable.